# PerSession WCF Service with Callback for Silverlight client

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, wcf-callbacks

We would like to develop WCF service for SL clients, which should support session management (PerSession) and callbacks. The WCF service would be hosted as a Windows service.

What would be best WCF binding choice (wsdual, pollingDuplex, any other)? Please also provide for/against points.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There are no others. Silverlight does not support WSDualHttpBinding. You can choose PollingDuplexHttpBinding or PollingDuplexHttpBinding.</strike>

Have been working a little more in this area and it appears this is an area of constant and recent change. As of Silverlight 4, NetTcpTransport and HttpTransport are both supported using either text or binary encoding. It appears SL5 delivers further enhancements.

There is an interesting benchmark app [here](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2010/03/comparison-of-http-polling-duplex-and.html) which allows you to profile relative performance of the two protocols. Though it was built for SL4, you can download, update the target framework to SL5 and see how it goes. It is a great way to make sure you've got everything setup properly.

Using NetTcpTransport should mean you can also use PerSession instancing on the server.

Comment: But does PollingDuplexHttpBinding support WCF sessions (PerSession)?

Comment: No, out of the box, sessions are not supported in Silverlight. However there are workarounds such as those discussed here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/317232/How-to-Build-Flexible-and-Reusable-WCF-Services